# How to add stuff I associated to migrations?

Tags: ruby, model-associations, sequel, padrino

I have a seemingly easy problem, but I have been unable to find a proper explanation (or I've just been too tired to see it). I have following migrations and models:

```
    class User < Sequel::Model
            one_to_many :orders
    end

    Sequel.migration do
            change do
                    create_table :users do
                            primary_key :id
                            String :name, :null=> false
                            String :password, :null=>false
                            create_table :user_orders do
                                  #like that? If so, what to put in here?
                            end
                    end    
            end
    end
```

and

```
    class Order < Sequel::Model
            many_to_one :user
            many_to_one :restaurant #ignore for now
    end

    Sequel.migration do
            change do
                    create_table :orders do
                            primary_key :id
                           #no stuff yet
                    end
            end


    end
```

My question is - how do I create a table in users and a single entry in orders to assign proper orders to user and proper user to an order. If I skipped some obvious source then I'm sorry in advance (new to ruby and whole web apps thing), and by all means point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is what you want, but as you can see in the [documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/association_basics_rdoc.html#label-many_to_one%2Fone_to_many), the `:orders` table should contain a foreign key to `:users`:

```
Sequel.migration do
  change do
    create_table :orders do
      primary_key :id
      foreign_key :user_id, :users
      #no stuff yet
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, I can see that - what about the other way around (users migration)? How would I create a table of orders?

Comment: In a one_to_many relationship you don't need anything in the "one" side - the :orders table holds the relation with the foreign key.

Comment: Oh, I see. So one last question - let's say I want to list users and their orders like [this](http://pastebin.com/Dn9iUPvR). How would I access the orders assigned to user?

Comment: `user.orders.each...`